# Add key to redux store for each component

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am using react/redux to make a table editor.

```
<TableContainer name="Users" />
```

In the container, I connect it to the redux store:

```
@connect((store)=> {
    return {
        tableData: store.tableData
    }
})
```

I have a reducer for tableData:

```
//tableDataReducer.js

const initialState = {
    fetchingRows: false,
    rows: [],
    selected: [],
    mass_editing_col_name: '',
    editing_row_id: null,
    //etc...
};
```

This works great when I only have one table on the page. But when I'm trying to use two tables on the same page, they both compete for `tableData` from the store:

```
<TableContainer name="Users" />
<TableContainer name="Products" />
//These tables both fight over store.tableData
```

I think I need to do something like this:

```
@connect((store)=> {
    return {
        tableData: store.tableData[this.props.name]
    }
})
//I don't have access to props though, and store.tableData.Users doesnt exist anyways!
```

So I have two questions:

1. How can I dynamically create `store.tableData.Users` and `store.tableData.Products` (using the initial state).
2. How can I access `props` in the `@connect` method to get access to the proper part of the store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do have access to props in @connect actually! With react-redux, the [mapStateToProps](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#arguments) callback accepts two arguments, the `state` and `ownProps`.

> If your mapStateToProps function is declared as taking two parameters,
>   it will be called with the store state as the first parameter and the
>   props passed to the connected component as the second parameter, and
>   will also be re-invoked whenever the connected component receives new
>   props as determined by shallow equality comparisons. (The second
>   parameter is normally referred to as ownProps by convention.)

Try this:

```
@connect((state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    tableData: state.tableData[ownProps.name]
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To create multiple tables with your initial state, you really want to create an instance of your table data for each component. One way you can do this is the following:

```
const initialState = {
    Users: {
        fetchingRows: false,
        rows: [],
        selected: [],
        mass_editing_col_name: '',
        editing_row_id: null,
        //etc...
    },
    Products: {
        fetchingRows: false,
        rows: [],
        selected: [],
        mass_editing_col_name: '',
        editing_row_id: null,
        //etc...
    }
}
```

You could also do something like:

```
const emptyDataTable = {
    fetchingRows: false,
    rows: [],
    selected: [],
    mass_editing_col_name: '',
    editing_row_id: null,
    //etc...
};

const initialState = {
    Users: object Object.assign({}, emptyDataTable),
    Products: Object.assign({}, emptyDataTable)
}
```